# What does Program Type Already exists means?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner to android studio, and I get the runtime error

```
Program type already present: 
android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil$DataCallback
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil$DataCallback, sources=[Unknown source 
file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I searched it up and I couldn't find anything, I think it might have something to do with my manifest file though. Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.dadei.cashmob">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Homescreen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".signup"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".videos"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Heres my dependencies. The error might be there as a well.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' //for Inmobi
compile name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
compile name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar'
```

I don't get an error when I sync my gradle, but just in case.

Comment: You have two same permissions: `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` try to remove one

Comment: @Yupi that didn't work, it still gives me the error

Comment: Can you show your `app gradle` this might have issue with dependencies you added in `gradle`

Comment: @Yupi I added my app gradle dependencies whenever I sync I don't get an error.

Comment: The thing is that more than one dependencie implements `android.support.v7.util.AsyncListUtil$DataCallback` which makes conflict and error is thrown. Try to update your dependencies to latest. I see you have: `27.1.0` and `27.1.1` also check those custom libraries you included. Also change `compile` to `implementation`

Comment: @Yupi I did that and still getting errors, I only got that error after I added something to my manifest, and then after removing it still got that error. I think I got an error in the code and pressed alt-enter by accident, and it already saved, so I couldn't undo it,